# Importing from react-navigation and I have an error for that

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I installed react-native the latest version and I made a 0.58.0 project. I installed react-navigation with `'npm install --save react-navigation'` and I have an error

This is the error

> Loading dependency graph, done. error: bundling failed: Error: Unable
>   to resolve module `react-native-gesture-handler` from `C:\Users\Zarzu
>   Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\Scrollables.js`:
>   Module `react-native-gesture-handler` does not exist in the Haste
>   module map
>
> This might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 To resolve try
>   the following:
>     1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>     2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>     3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
>     4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:273:16)
>       at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
>       at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:391:31)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:388:18)
>       at C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:261:33
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
>   DELTA  [android, dev] ....../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░ 98.6%
>   (591/666), failed.
>
> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2019:18:13:46 +0000] "GET
>   /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"

```
'''
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
'''
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install react-native-gesture-handler npm separately. They create separated npm package for touch & gesture handling and recognition.

Step 1.

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler
```

Step 2.

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Step 3.(optional )

If step 2 is not worked properly, code is not configured properly so we are manually configure it using step 3

To finalize the installation of react-native-gesture-handler for Android, be sure to make the necessary modifications to MainActivity.java:

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity; 
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate; 
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView; + import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView; 
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity { 
@Override 
protected String getMainComponentName() { return "Example"; } + 
@Override 
+ protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() { 
+ return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) { 
+ @Override + protected ReactRootView createRootView() { 
+ return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this); 
+ } 
+ }; 
+ } }
```

No additional steps are required for iOS.

Please Refer the following document for more information:-

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler/v/1.0.0-alpha.34?activeTab=readme

https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: I tried this too. But I will try and will let you an answer after that

Comment: does not metter. I have this problem now

Comment: C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\awesomeproject\MainActivity.java:6: error: package com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react does not exist
 import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
                                          ^
C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\awesomeproject\MainActivity.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);

Comment: do you add    ** implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')** into build.gradle file

Comment: include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')      into setting.gradlew file??

Comment: So what I need to include excatly where? Put the code into ' '

Comment: Inside android app level build.gradle

Comment: Yeah. But the code when. Because I do not understand exactly the second comment

Comment: Please check this                 https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/205#issuecomment-459993807

Comment: Thank you a lot for help

Comment: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-gesture-handler.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-gesture-handler: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: Now the program is built but is not loaded on the emulator

Comment: javascript : 0.58.0 and react-native: 0.59.2. I have a problem now

Comment: Close previously open node js server before run  application

Comment: Unable to resolve module `react-native-paper` for createMaterialBottomTabNavigator

Comment: Please install this package                         https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paper

Answer (score 1):

**Please  install [react-native-gesture-handle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler)r npm**

react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

And add this code into your MainActivity to create smooth navigation drawer

```
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
        @Override
        protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
            return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
        }
    };
}
```

**OR**

Please check [example project here](https://github.com/habeebrahmanpt/ReactNativeBoilerplate)